# Magento 2: Add custom binding to an element on the shipping.html knockout template

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I want to extend the `module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html` so that I can add a new custom binding to the shipping method options so that on init I can trigger another action. I have successfully loaded my `shipping.html` template and `shipping.js` files. However, I do not know how to get my `customBinding.js` file to be picked up by the `shipping.html`

I copied the `module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html` to my module `MyVendor/MyModule/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html` and modified the `<input name="shipping_method" type="radio"></input>` button to include a new binding as follows:

File: `MyVendor/MyModule/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html`

```
<input name="shipping_method" type="radio"
     data-bind="
         value: method.carrier_code + '_' + method.method_code,
         checked: $parent.isSelected,
         attr: {
            'id': 's_method_' + method.carrier_code + '_' + method.method_code,
            'aria-labelledby': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code + ' ' + 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code
              },
         click: $parent.selectShippingMethod,
         customBinding: $parent.isSelected"
class="radio"/>
```

I just created a simple custom binding following the instructions of how to do so from the [knockout.js tutorial on custom bindings](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=custombindings):

File: `MyVendor/MyModule/view/frontend/web/js/customBinding.js`

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "ko",
    "uiComponent"
], function($, ko, Component) {
    "use strict";

    ko.bindingHandlers.customBinding = {
       init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
           console.log("I am a custom binding");
           console.log(element);
           console.log(valueAccessor);
       }
    };

});
```

I changed the shipping component's js file to point to my `shipping.js`, which is where the template is specified.

File: `MyVendor/MyModule/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

```
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">MyVendor_MyModule/js/view/shipping</item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

This is the change i made to the `shipping.js` file so that it picked up my `shipping.html`  template instead of the default.

File: `MyVendor/MyModule/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js`

```
...
var popUp = null;
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'MyVendor_MyModule/shipping'
            },
...
```

Comment: Noemi Quezada, could you please be kind enough to help me understand how this was achieved? I am trying to achieve something of binding as my post explains. Could you please have a look at it and see if you can share some ideas? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/313927/magento-2-3-4-how-to-bind-an-event-handler-to-street0-input-on-the-checkout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got your example working using the module outlined below.

The module directory is as follows:

```
|   registration.php
|   
+---etc
|       module.xml
|       
\---view
    \---frontend
        +---layout
        |       checkout_index_index.xml
        |       
        \---web
            +---js
            |   \---view
            |           shipping.js
            |           
            \---template
                    shipping.html
```

**checkout_index_index.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Your_Module/js/view/shipping</item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**shipping.js** :

```
define([
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping',
    'ko'
], function (Shipping, ko) {
    'use strict';

    ko.bindingHandlers.customBinding = {
        init: function (element, valueAccesor) {
            console.log('I am a custom binding.');
            console.log(element);
            console.log(valueAccesor);
        }
    };

    return Shipping.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Your_Module/shipping'
        }
    });
});
```

**shipping.html** was copied from `Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html` and modified in the same way as what you posted.

Comment: I didn't see the updates you made until after I posted. Looks like all I did different is place the `ko.bindHandlers` directive inside of the `shipping.js` file.

Comment: Hi Aaron awesome, let me give your solution a whirl. Question, is that the only way we can add custom bindings?

Comment: @Aaron Allen, could you please be kind enough to help me understand how this was achieved? I am trying to achieve something of binding as my post explains. Could you please have a look at it and see if you can share some ideas? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/313927/magento-2-3-4-how-to-bind-an-event-handler-to-street0-input-on-the-checkout